# PHPUnit issue asserting mock is a ReflectionProperty object using Laravel

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit

I am new to PHPUnit and am trying to set up my first test. It is failing with the following error message

> Failed asserting that ReflectionProperty Object (...) is an instance of class "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model".

Essentially, I am trying to mock the creation of a model which I am injecting into a constructor and testing it is the right type through reflection. I am following the advice laid out in this post/answer:

> [How do I test this class using phpunit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893619/how-do-i-test-this-class-using-phpunit)

If anyone can give me some guidance, that would greatly appreciated.

The class being tested is here:

```
<?php

namespace PlaneSaleing\Repo\Listing;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EloquentListing implements ListingInterface {

    protected $advert;

    public function __construct(Model $advert)
    {
        $this->advert = $advert;
    }

    /**
     * Get paginated listings
     *
     * @param int  Current page
     * @param int Number of listings per page
     * @return StdClass object with $items and $totalItems for pagination
     */
    public function byPage($page=1, $limit=10)
    {

        $result = new \StdClass;
        $result->page = $page;
        $result->limit = $limit;
        $result->totalItems = 0;
        $result->items = array();

        $listings = $this->advert
                         ->orderBy('created_at')
                         ->skip( $limit * ($page-1) )
                         ->take($limit)
                         ->get();

        // Create object to return data useful for pagination
        $result->items = $listings->all();
        $result->totalItems = $this->totalListings();

        return $result;

    }
```

The service provider is here:

```
<?php

namespace PlaneSaleing\Repo;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use PlaneSaleing\Repo\Listing\EloquentListing as Listing;
use \Advert;

class RepoServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {

      $this->app->bind('PlaneSaleing\Repo\Listing\ListingInterface', function($app) {
        $app->make(Listing(new Advert));
      } );

    }

}
```

My Test is here:

```
<?php

use \Mockery;
use \ReflectionClass;
use PlaneSaleing\Repo\Listing\EloquentListing;

class EloquentListingTest extends \TestCase
{

    /**
     * Testing if __constructor is setting up property
     */
    public function testModelSetsUp()
    {
        $mock1 = Mockery::mock(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class);

        $listing = new EloquentListing($mock1);

        $reflection = new ReflectionClass($listing);

        // Making your attribute accessible
        $property1 = $reflection->getProperty('advert');
        $property1->setAccessible(true);

        $this->assertInstanceOf(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class, $property1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assert, you should use the actual value of the reflection property, not the property itself:

```
public function testModelSetsUp()
{
    $mock1 = Mockery::mock(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class);

    $listing = new EloquentListing($mock1);

    $reflection = new ReflectionClass($listing);

    // Making your attribute accessible
    $property1 = $reflection->getProperty('advert');
    $property1->setAccessible(true);

    $this->assertInstanceOf(
        Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class, 
        $property1->getValue($listing)
    );
}
```

However, you can simplify the test a lot:

```
public function testModelSetsUp()
{
    $mock1 = Mockery::mock(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class);

    $listing = new EloquentListing($mock1);

    $this->assertAttributeInstanceOf(
        Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class, 
        'advert', 
        $listing
    );
}
```

Even better, you could use meaningful variable names, use a meaningful test method name, and not just assert that the `$advert` property is an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, but actually the *same* instance as passed into the constructor:

```
public function testConstructorSetsAdvert()
{
    $advert = Mockery::mock(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class);

    $listing = new EloquentListing($advert);

    $this->assertAttributeSame(
        $advert,
        'advert',
        $listing
    );
}
```